# NFS file owenship inconsistent

Tags: nfs, sles11, oracle-linux

I am struggling with an issue setting up a new NFS client. We are using NFSv4.

The old NFS client is Red Hat 5 and I am replacing it with an Oracle Linux 7.3 box.

All of the NFS exporting has been done on the server side, and I am able to mound the remote directories. I'ver performed exportfs -a and restarted the nfsserver service afterwards.

The issue is, if I look at my old NFS client box, it shows all of the user:group owner as the nobody-user and nobody-group. When I mount the same share on my new NFS client, it is not mounting with the nobody-user and nobody-group owners (which is what I want). In the output below, the "old-nfsclient" has the desired behavior. Setgid is set on the "output" directory though I am not sure that factors in.

If I look at /proc/fs/nfs/exports, it shows both have the "root_squash" flag set. I've tried to switch to all_squash but then I get "access denied" when trying to mount.

My /etc/idmapd.config file has my DOMAIN set properly as well as the entries for nobody-user/group.

The anonuid and anongid is set on the NFS server. Those UID's match the same account and group on the NFS client.

nfs-server01

```
nfs-server01:/data/BDEVLT/output/over-7-days # ll
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users    310 Jan 11 07:00 SZRC04S_10805256.txt
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users    310 Jan 11 07:00 SZRC04S_10805257.txt
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users   4362 Jan 11 07:00 SZRF04S_10805255.txt
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users   4939 Jan 27 08:38 szrgadi_201760.csv
```

old-nfsclient

```
old-nfsclient over-7-days# ll
-rw-r----- 1 appsmgr users    310 Jan 11 07:00 SZRC04S_10805256.txt
-rw-r----- 1 appsmgr users    310 Jan 11 07:00 SZRC04S_10805257.txt
-rw-r----- 1 appsmgr users   4362 Jan 11 07:00 SZRF04S_10805255.txt
-rw-r----- 1 appsmgr users   4939 Jan 27 08:38 szrgadi_201760.csv
```

new-nfsclient

```
new-nfsclient over-7-days# ll
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users    310 Jan 11 07:00 SZRC04S_10805256.txt
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users    310 Jan 11 07:00 SZRC04S_10805257.txt
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users   4362 Jan 11 07:00 SZRF04S_10805255.txt
-rw-r----- 1 oracle users   4939 Jan 27 08:38 szrgadi_201760.csv
```

nfs-server01 /etc/exports (uid 2068 = appsmgr, 1000 = users)

```
/data/BDEVLT/output old-nfsclient.ourdomain.com(rw,fsid=0,async,anonuid=2068,anongid=1000)
/data/BDEVLT/output new-nfsclient.ourdomain.com(rw,fsid=0,async,anonuid=2068,anongid=1000)
```

old-nfsclient /etc/fstab

```
nfs-server01.ourdomain.com:/ /mnt/BDEVLT/output nfs4 defaults 0 0
```

new-nfsclient /etc/fstab

```
nfs-server01.ourdomain.com:/ /mnt/BDEVLT/output nfs4 defaults 0 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

I've changed paths for obfuscation so please ignore path typos, I am sure those are all set properly.

Comment: So what user is uid 2068 on the new machine?

Comment: That is the appsmgr user, sorry. and 1000 is the std users group.